# Adding and refreshing in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have array with objects. I'm using method map to render on website. After click on button I want to add next object to this array and refresh list. How should I do it?

```
const todayQuestsArray = [
    {
      hardness: "easy",
      title: "reQuest",
      date: "Today:" + Date().slice(16, 21),
      type: "Health",
      isQuest: true,
    },
    {
      hardness: "easy",
      title: "reQuest",
      date: "Today:" + Date().slice(16, 21),
      type: "Health",
      isQuest: true,
    },
  ];

<ul className={css.today_section_list}>
              {todayQuestsArray.map((quest) => (
                <li>
                  <Tile
                    difficultyLevel={quest.hardness}
                    title={quest.title}
                    date={quest.date}
                    type={quest.type}
                  />
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>

const [quest, setQuest] = useState([]);

<AddButton
          target={todayQuestsArray}
          onClick={() =>setQuest (
            <ul className={css.tomorrow_section_list}>
              {tomorrowQuestsArray.map((quest) => (
                <li>
                  <Tile
                    difficultyLevel={quest.hardness}
                    title={quest.title}
                    date={quest.date}
                    type={quest.type}
                    isQuest={quest.isQuest}
                  />
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          )}
        ></AddButton>
```

I was thinking about useEffect or useState but didn't work.

Comment: Please show what you have tried with `useState`

Comment: I edited the code. I'm trying all time

Comment: https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/rendering-lists

Answer (score 0):

```
<AddButton
      target={todayQuestsArray}
      onClick={() =>setQuest (
        <ul className={css.tomorrow_section_list}>
          {tomorrowQuestsArray.map((quest) => (
            <li>
              <Tile
                difficultyLevel={quest.hardness}
                title={quest.title}
                date={quest.date}
                type={quest.type}
                isQuest={quest.isQuest}
              />
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      )}
    ></AddButton>
```

Instead, you should do this:

```
  <AddButton
      target={todayQuestsArray}
      onClick={() =>setQuest([
         ...quest,
         {
           hardness: "what is the meaning",
           title: "what is the meaning",
           date: "what is the meaning",
           type: "what is the meaning",
           isQuest: what is the meaning,
         }
         ])}
   ></AddButton>
```

Also, the initial data must be in the state:

```
const [quest, setQuest] = useState(
[{
  hardness: "easy",
  title: "reQuest",
  date: "Today:" + Date().slice(16, 21),
  type: "Health",
  isQuest: true,
},
{
  hardness: "easy",
  title: "reQuest",
  date: "Today:" + Date().slice(16, 21),
  type: "Health",
  isQuest: true,
},]);
```

The state itself(const [quest, setQuest] = useState()) must be at the top level